# What is a Muslim obliged to donate while earning an income?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat, work

I have had a bitter career which lots of job being lost but now I am in new job which has let me to ask myself what do I need to give in name of Allah, how much donation/charity or what I am eligible too? What is the threshold/minimum requirements for a Muslim to keep charity as I have heard that if your in loss, do business with Allah. Even after earning so much I tend to be unhappy and I believe due to my lack of knowledge for my contribution is the cause. 
So what is required of a Muslim to give in Allah way and what should be the minimum earning/saving?

Answer (score 1):

The usually followed minimum threshold for a person is the value equivalent to 21 ounces of silver (612.36 grams). Your wealth comes from work earnings, which makes you obliged to pay 2.5% of of your net savings - ie, deducting the debt you owe. People usually pay during the month of Ramadan, but strictly speaking you need only pay it within one year of your wealth crossing the threshold.

Comment: To clarify, it's one lunar year :)